# Ffmpeg split video into multiple chunk but in different duration length

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, fluent-ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I know how to split video into equal duration length, but here i want to split video into un-equal parts and number of parts and duration will be different for each time.

```
For ex, video length is 50 sec, i want to split it in 4 parts. 
1) 0 sec - 5 sec 
2) 6 sec - 22 sec
3) 23 sec - 34 sec
4) 35 sec - 50 sec
```

Comment: I assume you don't intend to leave one-second gaps out of the output files, right? So you really want 0-5, 5;01-22, 22;01-34, ...

Answer (score 3):

If you're capturing and segmenting all the input, use something like

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 0,5,22,34,50 output%d.mp4
```

Comment: It is not working, it creates blank video in different duration.

Comment: Try with a different codec than "copy". Either leave off the `-c copy` altogether or specify your preferred encoding.

Comment: Ugh. Sorry. The `-vn` means no video. (A holdover from a different use of this).

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for audio, then you can try this, modifying a version of @L. Scott Johnson

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.mp3 -c copy -f segment -segment_times 5,22,34,50 output%d.mp3
```